# PowerShell 7Zip4Powershell zipping .zip error

Tags: powershell, 7zip

Currently have a PSscript that does 1.65tb of .bmp files sorted into folders by yyyy/MM/dd/HH, replaces the @ in the file name then converted to .jpg.
What I can't get past is the next step which gives me an error because it tries to zip the zip file that was created. 
How to I prevent that? I tried the -Exclude but I think it has to be done just before the actual compression happens.
tried -Append and it fails for file not found.
(last step is delete the files that were zipped but I believe that can be done with a Remove-Item)

Directory structure looks like this with files in youngest child directory:

```
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\13
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\14
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\15
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\16
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\17
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\18
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\19
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\20
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\21
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\22
D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\23
```

PowerShell script

```
$sourceRootPath = "D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13"
$targetRootPath = "D:\Test\Processed\2020\Archived"
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude *.zip | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
    $directoryFullName = $_.FullName
    $directoryName = $_.Name
#$folderPathToCompress - redundant but keeps my thinking straight for now
    $folderPathToCompress = $directoryFullName

# This creates an error that the .zip file does not exist and exits
    #Compress-7Zip -Path $folderPathToCompress -ArchiveFileName $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip -Format Zip -CompressionLevel Ultra -Append

    # This creates the .zip file BUT creates an error when it tries to zip the .zip file it is creating
    #Compress-7Zip -Path $folderPathToCompress -ArchiveFileName $directoryFullName\$directoryName.zip -Format Zip -CompressionLevel Ultra 

}
```

I will get this posting stuff figure out, sorry for the errors, I am open to learning two things at once but it takes 4x longer... so back at it.

1.) I am using the 7Zip4Powershell Module - it looked like a good idea, but maybe I should stick with passing everything to a variable and then Invoke-Expression thus not use the module but the 7zip command directly(?)

2.) Made a few attempts with same results but issue not resolved ... yet
This is what the error looks like and the different attempts below.

```
Compress-7Zip : The process cannot access the file 'D:\Test\Processed\2020\01\13\13\13.zip' because it is being used by another process.
At C:\Users\moe3srv\Desktop\test2.ps1:19 char:6
+     (Compress-7Zip -Path $folderPathToCompress -ArchiveFileName $dire ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (SevenZip4PowerS...+CompressWorker:CompressWorker) [Compress-7Zip], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : err01,SevenZip4PowerShell.Compress7Zip
```

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse) 
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude .zip )
(Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude *.zip )
```

Comment: if you wrap the G-CI call in `()` it will grab all the _current files_. then it will pass the list on to the pipeline. your problem is caused by the G-CI call picking up files that are added before the last file is sent to the pipeline.

Comment: Stumped on how to enter code here so sorry it does not look right but (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude *.zip | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} ) did not work nor did (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude *.zip) or this (Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceRootPath -Recurse -Exclude *.zip | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} ) Can you give me a better clue, please. And Thank-you for responding Mr. Dailey

Comment: put additional info - and code - in your Question as added info. ///// for the `()` suggestion, wrap ONLY the G-CI call in parens - nothing else. that would be the part before the 1st pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in PowerShell we can user [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1)
eg,

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Reference\* -DestinationPath C:\Archives\Draft.zip
```